# Check if a URL is still active or Permanently Moved

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to check if a URL still active or it returns a 301 Redirect code using chhttp?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've answered your own question - use CFHTTP.

```
<cfhttp method="head" url="http://www.google.com" result="myResult">
<cfdump var="#myResult#">
```

You'll see that myResult struct contains "Responseheader" struct with "Status_Code" field in it. It will contain the numeric status code.
If you don't need numeric you can just use myResult.Statuscode - returns something like "200 OK".

If the url will be incorrect or there will be some issues with reaching the target, the "Responseheader" will be empty.

**Addendum after the comment:**

If you want to know the redirect location after 301 use CFHTTP with trace or options as method.

```
<cfhttp method="trace" url="http://www.google.com" result="myResult">
```

The result should contain the "Status_Code" as above as well as "Location" - the url to redirect to.

Comment: Actually I wanted it the URL is Moved Permanently It should return new Path. Is it Possible?

Comment: As stated in the answer by Lucas the cfhttp.responseHeader.Location or in your example myResult.Location variable contains the (new) redirection path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the redirect attribute (e.g. redirect="false") in cfhttp tag. Then you get the original response and can figure out what http code was sent back to your request.